# jQuery force to refresh data from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using range slider and it outputs data into an input field. I'm trying to multiply that data by 50 and show the result under it, **but the script only works when I manually input data into that field**.

For example, if you write 5 in that field, you'll get 250, but if you just move the slider, nothing will change.

How can I force jQuery to refresh the data?

```
jQuery("#slidervalue").change(function(){
  var unit = parseFloat(jQuery(".unit").attr("data-init-unit"));
  var multiplier = parseInt(jQuery("#slidervalue").val());
  jQuery(".unit").html(unit * multiplier);
});
```

Here's the full JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/2tjx7e19/**

Thank you!

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page to make a [mre] here on Stack Overflow so we can tell what element is your slider and what is your textbox. I can tell you without looking that `change` events only fire when the user changes a value, not when JavaScript changes the value...

Comment: I think you could just add `var unit = parseFloat(jQuery(".unit").attr("data-init-unit"));` and 
   `jQuery(".unit").html(unit * data.from);` as the new lines 18 and 19, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the `change` and `keyup` events, and handle the update of the slider only on `keyup`.

Then, when you update the input value based on the slider, you can trigger the `change` event programatically.

See this fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uand5wfx/3/

Updated:

To skip the input altogether, you can set set the content of the output element when the slider `update` function is called. The code gets a lot shorter this way. Check out this new fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3jk5s4tg/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, Romi! Is there a way to skip the input part altogether and just multiply the sliderdata and output the result?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use the `update` method of the slider to set the content of the html element. Check out the updated answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again! By the way, I'm just curious, isn't there an option in JavaScript to store a function in a variable and call it like `$total` or something? Just so you don't repeat the whole function twice.

Comment: Oh, I just did! `var $sliderdata = function(data)` and it worked. Cheers!